# API to fetch Oro Commerce Attribute list and details

Tags: orocommerce

We are searching for REST API to get all Attributes in OroCommerce

Thank you in Advance for help

Regards
Satish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
GET /index.php/admin/api/entitystructures/product
```

All the attributes will be listed in the "fields" section along with other product entity fields.

Comment: Thank You Andrey, Let me check